# Why is my UIViewController initializer never called?

Tags: iphone

I made a view-based project from a fresh template. There's a UIViewController which is created with an XIB.

In the implementation I uncommented that and added an NSLog. But this is never called:

```
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if ((self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil])) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"nib");
    }
    return self;
}
```

since that is initialized from a nib / xib, that should be called for sure, right? however, it doesn't. I do get an NSLog message when I put that in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Where is the code initializing the View controller?

Answer (score 5):

When an object is initialized from nib/xib, the [`-initWithCoder:` method](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:) will be used for initialization.

`-initWithNibName:…` is never used in unarchiving.